# XMI to XML by using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, uml, xmi

Please i'm beginner in XSLT. Can some one explain for me how transform this XMI file to XML file ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projet:Config xmi:version="2.0" xmlns:xmi="http://www.omg.org/XMI" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:test="http://projet.org/test" xmlns:occi="http://schemas.ogf.org/projet">
<use href="extensions/plugin.xmi#/"/>

<group id="group1">
    <type href="extensions/plugin#//[term='host']"/>
    <variable name="v1" value="x86"/>
    <variable name="v2"  value="Linux"/>
    <variable name="v3"  value="Xen"/>  
</group>

</projet:Config>
```

to tansform the previous XMI to xml file such as:

```
<host v1="x86" v2="Linux" v3="Xen">
```

Comment: Have you made an attempt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many many ways to do this. Here's one: Start with a template to match the root node to give you a valid root tag (this is assuming your `group` nodes are repeatable); have a template below that which matches the `group` nodes, and a template below that that matches the `variable` nodes in that group.  Build your attributes in the `variable` template.

Note that your input XML is invalid and may cause problems - that `projet` prefix is undeclared, which is why I'm referencing it using the `local-name()` syntax.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <root>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </root>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/*[local-name()='Config']/group">
       <xsl:element name="{type/substring-before(substring-after(@href,'term='''), ''']')}">
          <xsl:apply-templates />
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="variable">
        <xsl:attribute name="{@name}"><xsl:value-of select="@value" /></xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template match="text()" />
</xsl:transform>
```

Comment: It is truen when i run the command line `xsltproc -o test.xml config.xsl config.xmi` i obtain an error `config.xmi:4: namespace error : Namespace prefix projet on Config is not defined` How can i correct this error please ? and another question, there is another method to obtain an xml file more easier than  command line ?

Comment: You have to add the namespace declaration to the root node of the input: `xmlns:projet="www.tempuri.org"`.  Alternatively, remove the `projet` prefix altogether from the input document.  Alternatively, find an XSLT processor that will tolerate such errors in the XML.

Comment: Thank you. 
It work but i have this error "compilation error: file config.xsl line 2 element transform".
Can you suggest for me some documentation ?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not even sure what processor you're using and I'm not very familiar with all the options out there for the various processors.